# Make Service test to return filtered list, how to do it when input parameter is id?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have Service class containing this method:

```
public List<Tag> getSegmentByTypeSaved(String mailChimpListId) {

        List<Tag> tags = mailChimpClient.listTags(mailChimpListId);

        List<Tag> listOfSegmentsByTypeSaved = tags.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(TagType.SAVED))
                .map(y -> new Tag(y.getId(), y.getName(), y.getUpdatedAt(), y.getMemberCount(), y.getType()))
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Tag::getUpdatedAt).reversed())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return listOfSegmentsByTypeSaved;
    }
```

I want to create a test to test if the service work as i want. Test class until now is:

```
@Test
    public void getFiltredListByTypeSaved() {

        Tag tagOne = new Tag(1, "Test One", LocalDate.now().minusDays(2).toString(), 5, TagType.SAVED);
        Tag tagTwo = new Tag(2, "Test Two", LocalDate.now().minusDays(5).toString(), 5, TagType.STATIC);

        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        tags.add(tagOne);
        tags.add(tagTwo);

        // Check if list has size of two after filtered

       // Check if list have the properties as above only for SAVED

       // Check if list if sorted by attribute eg: LocalDate
```

How can i mock so the service actually return me the filtered list? My Service class method take id as input parameter. This line of code in service class `List<Tag> tags = mailChimpClient.listTags(mailChimpListId);` returns me the `tags` list with different object containing type "saved" and "static". But in my test i want to test that i only get a list of only `TagType.SAVED`.

My `MailChimpService` class:

```
@Inject
public MailChimpService(MailChimpClient mailChimpClient,
                        MailChimpRepository mailChimpRepository,
                        ProductService productService,
                        SchoolService schoolService,
                        SchoolYearService schoolYearService,
                        SchoolYearConfigService schoolYearConfigService,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.customer.list}") String mailChimpCustomerListId,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.customer.smspermission}") String mailChimpCustomerSmsPermission,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.customer.emailpermission}") String mailChimpCustomerEmailPermission,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.schooladmin.list}") String mailChimpSchoolAdminListId,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.schooladmin.smspermission}") String mailChimpSchoolAdminSmsPermission,
                        @Value("${mailchimp.schooladmin.emailpermission}") String mailChimpSchoolAdminEmailPermission
) {
    this.mailChimpClient = mailChimpClient;
    this.mailChimpRepository = mailChimpRepository;
    this.productService = productService;
    this.schoolService = schoolService;
    this.schoolYearService = schoolYearService;
    this.schoolYearConfigService = schoolYearConfigService;
    this.mailChimpCustomerListId = mailChimpCustomerListId;
    this.mailChimpCustomerEmailPermission = mailChimpCustomerEmailPermission;
    this.mailChimpCustomerSmsPermission = mailChimpCustomerSmsPermission;
    this.mailChimpSchoolAdminListId = mailChimpSchoolAdminListId;
    this.mailChimpSchoolAdminEmailPermission = mailChimpSchoolAdminEmailPermission;
    this.mailChimpSchoolAdminSmsPermission = mailChimpSchoolAdminSmsPermission;
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, as you mentioned, the MailChimpClient will return a list of mixed TagTypes, and your service method will filter them out. That is what you should exactly do with your test as well. What I simply did was to mock the MailChimpClient and return a list of mixed Tag elements when invoked.

```java
class FooServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private MailChimpClient mailChimpClient;

    private FooService fooService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.fooService = new FooService(mailChimpClient);
    }

    @Test
    void getFilteredListByTypeSaved() {
        String mailChimpListId = "id";

        final List<Tag> tags = List.of(
                new Tag(1, "Test One", LocalDate.now().minusDays(2).toString(), 5, TagType.SAVED),
                new Tag(2, "Test Two", LocalDate.now().minusDays(5).toString(), 5, TagType.STATIC),
                new Tag(1, "Test Three", LocalDate.now().minusDays(2).toString(), 5, TagType.SAVED),
                new Tag(2, "Test Four", LocalDate.now().minusDays(5).toString(), 5, TagType.STATIC),
                new Tag(1, "Test Five", LocalDate.now().minusDays(2).toString(), 5, TagType.SAVED),
                new Tag(2, "Test Six", LocalDate.now().minusDays(5).toString(), 5, TagType.STATIC)
        );
        // mocking the class to return a list of tags when invoked
        Mockito.when(mailChimpClient.listTags(mailChimpListId))
                .thenReturn(tags);

        // actual invocation
        final List<Tag> result = fooService.getSegmentByTypeSaved(mailChimpListId);

        // assertions
        // assert the actual size of the result
        Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
        Assertions.assertEquals(3, result.size());
        // assertions related to the actual content of the result
        final Set<TagType> typeSet = result.stream().map(Tag::getType).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Assertions.assertEquals(1, typeSet.size());
        Assertions.assertEquals(TagType.SAVED, typeSet.iterator().next());

        Mockito.verify(mailChimpClient, Mockito.times(1)).listTags(eq(mailChimpListId));
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the post. Added my constructor in `MailChimpService` class. When i try to create the `this.mailChimpService = new MailChimpService(mailChimpClient);` its required to have all these injected in the constructor. How to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: You can mock all the classes and put fake values for @Value annotated inputs. If you have those dependencies, probably you are using them in other methods that you would like to test anyways. So, mock them all and pass as arguments to the constructor.

Comment: But why `        final Set<TagType> typeSet = result.stream().map(Tag::getType).collect(Collectors.toSet());
` ? I want to populate new Tag object for all object where `TagType.SAVED`

Comment: No, that's the result of the method you want to rest, I just added it to a set, so that there won't be any duplicates and we will know if all the tags are actually `SAVED`.

Comment: What does this code do? `        Mockito.verify(mailChimpClient, Mockito.times(1)).listTags(eq(mailChimpListId));` ?

Comment: It verifies that the mock has been called with `listTags` method with `mailChimpListId` string parameter. It is necessary because you method for example, might return a response without even calling the mocked object. It is just to verify everything going according to the plan. In this case, the mocked object is called once, so I set `times(1)`, if it was called twice, in this case the test would fail.

Comment: But is there any way to avoid creating mock of all services and the @Value's ?

Comment: Maybe you can make them null. But if you do and they are invoked, an NPE will be thrown.